# CMake: Target links to transitive dependency target but the target was not found

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a simple cmake setup between two projects, a library project and an executable project. The library project I want to be installed on the system (Linux container), and the executable project I want to link with the library package after finding it with find_package(XXX CONFIG). I successfully build and install the library project just fine, however, when I configure the executable project I get an error in the vein of

> CMake Error at MyExecutable/CMakeLists.txt:35 (add_executable):
> Target "MyExecutable" links to target "CUDA::toolkit" but the target was
> not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
> target, or an ALIAS target is missing?

CUDA::toolkit is a PRIVATE target linked to the library project.

The CMakeLists.txt for the library project looks like this

```
add_library(SiftCuda ${SOURCES} ${CUDA_KERNELS})
target_link_libraries(MyLibrary PRIVATE
    CUDA::cudart
    CUDA::cublas
)

set_target_properties(MyLibrary PROPERTIES 
    PUBLIC_HEADER "${HEADERS}" 
    CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON
)

target_include_directories(MyLibrary PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>  
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/MyLibrary>
)

target_compile_features(MyLibrary PUBLIC 
    cxx_std_11
)

# Alias library
add_library(MyLibrary::MyLibrary ALIAS MyLibrary)

###### Installation  #####
include(GNUInstallDirs)

# Install library
install(TARGETS MyLibrary
    EXPORT MyLibraryConfig
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/MyLibrary
)

# For exposing internal configuration of the package
export(
    TARGETS MyLibrary
    NAMESPACE MyLibrary::
    FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLibraryConfig.cmake"
)

# Install exports
install(EXPORT MyLibraryConfig
    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/MyLibrary"
    NAMESPACE MyLibrary::
)
```

The CMakeLists.txt for the executable looks like this

```
find_package(MyLibrary CONFIG)
add_executable(MyExe
    ${SOURCES}
)

target_link_libraries(MyExe PUBLIC
    MyLibrary::MyLibrary
)
```

I get the feeling that linking MyExe to the CUDA targets would resolve this issue, however, doing so seems incorrect as I usually don't have to be aware of transitive dependencies for libraries I use.

Comment: Is `MyLibrary` a **shared** or **static** library? While you may PRIVATE'ly link a static library using `target_link_libraries`, that linkage is still propagated to the consumer of this library.

Comment: Making it a shared library fixed it. Thanks. I was under  the impression I was already building it as shared but that was wrong.

Comment: Note: if you want to support the library being built as a static library, you could either just leave it to the consuming project to make some changes to how you create your import config file and add a call to [`find_dependency`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.html) in it. I might be completely wrong here though, since I haven't used `find_dependency` myself